How bad would near constant dreary/gloomy/stormy weather on our or an Earthlike world be for us and the environment?
So I have this idea to have the world(or maybe just a country/continent) be covered in gloomy and stormy weather with maybe only moments of sunny weather here and there in lieu of having it be post apocalyptic, as I feel it would limit my story.
I have not figured a source of this, maybe a somewhat strong volcanic eruption or just an unknown force affecting the weather. It is not super wet or anything as it only rains as it normally does and the winds might dry some of it up. Also should note this is not nighttime or strong thunderstorm level darkness, just the same level of dimming as a mild rain or thunderstorm would bring, so like earlymid morning lighting. Oh, and this has been a thing for only 5 to 8 years, so not too old of a phenomenon.
My question is how would this affect the world? Would plants all die off? How would humans be directly affected by this? And the animals also? Would it still be really bad if it was, say, only the USA? I can handwave it, but I still would like to know the implications of this.

The Netherlands fits the bill in terms of months of gloomy weather. Have you checked how does it fare?

Not all plants would die off, but all of the plants which we grow for food would die. Humans will dies soon after. (Most cereals need an illumination of about 15,000 lux to grow.)

@L.Dutch: Perhaps surprisingly, in summer the Netherlands gets about 40% to 45% of the maximum possible sunshine hours. It is not the 60% to 80% of Italy, but it is still respectable.

"maybe a somewhat strong volcanic eruption" on that note, I want to introduce you to the year 1816. Volcanic eruption did not over the earth in constant darkness. It did, however, expel enough particles that reflected light to cool down the Earth.

"How bad would near constant dreary/gloomy/stormy weather on our or an Earthlike world be for us?" You're describing Blighty, the mother of the industrial revolution and the largest empire the world has ever seen, so yes, that would be really awful for those who had to suffer it ;p

VTC:NAW([help]) for violating the book rule, but I could also VTC:NMF for asking (patently) more than one question. I'm tempted to down vote for failing to research the near constant dreary/gloomy/stormy weather of locations like Portland, Oregon (USA). (Note: some people who live in those climes like it. Calling it dreary and gloomy is a judgement that need not be shared by your fictional inhabitants.)

This question is obviously WB related, point out the plot based question if you can. In fact, tell me even an inkling of what my story is about since this is a plot based question in your opinion.Is climate and its effects not WB in your opinion? Saying this is for a book does not mean plot based question. And I mean dreary in more of a objective setting descriptor, I personally like that type of weather and vibe. @JBH

@ConanHighwoods The VTC reason is specifically, "This question doesn't meet a Worldbuilding Stack Exchange guideline." The guideline it's violating (among several) is the book rule (see [help/dont-ask]), which is defined as "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." In other words, it's way too broad and therefore out of scope. How would this affect the world? The whole world? That's impossible to answer meaningfully without writing answers the length of books. BTW, based on your comment, you really need to read the [help]. Badly.

The Scots are a bit weird, so are the Nordic countries, but otherwise find.

@AlexP that is what global warming does. More extreme weather. Suddenly the sun breaks through the clouds in the Netherlands. All life gets confused.

@Trioxidane The Netherlands gets above-average sunshine.  World-wide average is around 30%.

You are just nitpicky at this point, go build a cool new world or something. @JBH

Pay attention, @ConanHighwoods. Your comment demonstrated that you fundamentally misunderstood what I had done and why. I'm trying to instruct you so you can avoid this problem in the future. Your edits have solved none of the problems I mentioned. Please consider using the Sandbox, which others are using with considerable success.

Come to Ireland and experience the joy of living in year round gloomy weather. There's reasons we're so fond of the drink, and the weather is one of those reasons.

There is no problem but the one you are making. Worldbuilding can scope worldwide and beyond, nothing wrong with asking questions at this scale. @JBH

Bergen Norway had 23 inches of rain this month. In January, they get only 5 hours of faint sunshine if it breaks through the clouds. People become "sun worshipers" and try to soak up any sunshine they can get. Grasses grow in that environment and historically, people have raised sheep, goats, and cattle for the milk.

I can't help myself... @ConanHighwoods, is that what you'd tell a police officer after you'd been caught for speeding? "I'm sorry officer, but there is no problem but the one you are making." Cheers, mate. I voted to close your question and politely explained why including references to the law... I mean [help]... which I'm not obligated to do. You're welcome. In the future I won't waste my time explaining the problem.

Life will be fine as long as it's not the result of rapid climate change.
The rainiest place in the world is Mawsynram India which gets 11,800 millimeters (465 inches) of rain per year.  Yet, despite raining 9 to 31 days per month, it is a major agricultural region for India which grows significant amounts of flood resistant cereal crops like rice and corn.  As for wildlife, it is a very green place full of things like bamboo, broom grass, orchids, and pitcher plants and has a rich variety of wildlife including leopards and various kinds of bovines and deer.
However, if your focus is more on cloudy weather, again, this is not a thing that prevents life anywhere on Earth.  The place on Earth with the least sun (due to cloud cover) is El Danubio in Cauca, Colombia with an average cloud cover of 98.6%.  This region is characterized by its dense and ecologically diverse rainforests and has a rich agricultural sector with major crops including sugar cane, corn, rice, bananas, agave, yucca, potatoes, coconut, sorghum, cocoa, and palm.
The exact plants that thrive in rainy/cloudy places like these are different than more consistently sunny places, but those flora and fauna that like such conditions do very well there.
The biggest issue is if this is a recent or natural state of being.  These places thrive because all the wildlife and agriculture there has been selected for, but if this is from something recent like a volcano, then farmers may not be able to simply pivot to lower light, shorter season, or wetter whether crops on the turn of a dime, and wildlife may experience a major die off if what is there is not designed to live like that.
The last consideration is that humans tend to not do as well mentally if we don't get enough sunlight.  People living in low light areas tend to be more vulnerable to Vitamin-D and Serotonin deficiency.  Humans need typically 4-8 times as much outside time in indirect sun to maintain ideal Vitamin-D and Serotonin production.  But just like plants and wildlife, humans are also diverse.  Some humans are genetically much more predisposed to low sunlight disorders such as Jaundice and Seasonal Affective Disorder, and others do just fine with very little sunlight... but as a measure of simple survivability, humans have been making it work just fine in low light regions for quite a while now.

Wikipedia says that from May to September Seattle gets 54% to 59% of the maximum possible number of sunshine hours. This is a larger percentage of the maximum possible number of sunshine hours than Paris gets. From May to September, Seattle gets on the average 1,337 hours of sunshine, compared to 1,017 hours for Paris and 1,170 hours for Milan...

Washington State is a dry, warm, and sunny place.  It is certainly sunnier, drier, and warmer than anywhere I've ever lived.  OP is not describing Washington State.

@AlexP It does have sunny summers, but a 9 month cloudy season from fall through spring where they get very little direct sunlight.

This is misleading. Washington is divided in half by a mountain range: the western half is where we get most of the rain and clouds, but the eastern half is where most of the farming happens.

@PoeticallyPsychotic That is fair, given how big Washington State is, it may have been an overgeneralization.  Instead I've focused my real world examples on much smaller and more specific places: the rainiest and cloudiest places on Earth respectively.  That said, my conclusions are the same.  Neither rain nor clouds at any scale seen on Earth make an area inhospitable to life.

Yeah, it is rather recent, probably like 5 or so years of it.

Okay if the effect is so short lived (and is not intended to continue for decades) you can even have stronger effects without causing anything unrecoverable. Five years is more like a "weather phenomenon", not (yet) a global climate changing event. The final results depend on the duration after an extended period of time under the haze (talking decades to centuries here and only if the haze is a global effect everywhere).

@Antares Depend on if he means it lasts for 5 years, or just started 5 years ago.  Yes, 5 year weather phenomenons have already happened during human history many times.  The REALLY big stuff that wipes out a species has climate changing effects that last for thousands of years. But a really big thing that happened 5 years ago may last for another 5000 years.

It depends on the incoming sunlight at the ground.
As I understand, the effect of that "haze" is global. So there are no zones with "normal" weather, which would get "normal amount" of sunlight because of earth's rotation (=day/night-cycle). If there are zones without haze, this would ease the effects "under the haze" to a certain degree.
I don't have numbers at hand, but if you intend the haze being about 10-25% in strength, then the results would probably not change much of what we know. It might get a little colder globally, maybe. Depending on the time this effect lasts.
It is also dependent on the kind of substance the haze is made of. In your case I assume it is just clouds of water vapor/droplets, as earth has them normally in the atmosphere.
If there are particles like smoke, smog, dust, ash, sand, etc. involved their sun-blocking properties are much more severe usually. Those particles are also the source for increasingly changed weather conditions. They can serve as cloud seeds for rain and hail (see weather modification).
If the sunlight blocking effects become too strong, temperature drops are to be expected. In the worst case this will bring the whole planet into an "fallout winter" state (like a "nuclear winter", just without the nuclear aspect).
In case you didn't know: This really happened on earth after the impact of the Chixulub-Asteroid 66mio. years ago (the "dinosaur-killer"). An extreme fallout winter with sun blocking effects of 80-100% would be a certain death sentence for almost any life on earth.

Clouds do not consist of water vapour.

@gerrit: They don't? Enlighten me, please.

I guess they meant like droplets as vapor is gas. @Antares

Oh, I see! Thanks, I'll edit. The gas state is needed to get into the atmosphere in the first place, but then it cools off to droplets of course.


My question is how would this affect the world?

It would affect selected industries, such as the tourism industry, the solar power industry, and parts of the agricultural industry (we would grow different crops).  There would be no major impact on society.

Would plants all die off?

No.  There would be different plants, that are adapted to the climate.

How would humans be directly affected by this?

Maybe they would all turn a little happier, friendlier, more social democratic.  After all, Finnish people are supposed to be the happiest people in the world, and Iceland and Norway are not far off.  Those are not countries known for their nice weather (nor nice food).  There are correlations between climate and culture, although outliers too (Alaska has very different politics from northern Sweden).  One can speculate at length about the causes for those correlations.

And the animals also?

No.  On the land, there would be different animals that can handle the climate.  In the sea, impact would probably be negligible.

Would it still be really bad if it was, say, only the USA?

It would not be really bad either way, but if it only affects some countries but not others, the tourism industry might be relatively more affected, as sun-loving people would travel to sunnier destinations for their beach holidays.

Clouds help stabilize temperatures; so, cold-blooded animals may actually do exceptionally well in certain cloudy regions.  Tropical cloud forests for example tend to have plenty of reptiles.

@Nosajimiki You're right, of course.  I was thinking of reptiles baking in the sun, but they don't need to if it's warm enough.  Removed that line.
